# Null-homotopic embedded circle in surface bounds disk

Tags: homotopy-theory, surfaces

The following is stated all over, for instance in Hatcher's Notes on 3-Manifold Topology: A null-homotopic embedded circle in a surface bounds a disk in the surface. I can't seem to find or come up with a proof of this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $S$ be the surface, assumed to be connected. Let $\gamma \subset S$ be the null-homotopic embedded circle. We must find an embedded disc in $S$ with boundary $\gamma$.

If $S$ is the sphere or the plane, this is just the [Schönflies Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schoenflies_problem).

Otherwise, consider a universal covering map $f : X \to S$ and let $\tilde\gamma \subset X$ be a homeomorphic lift of $\gamma$. From the classification of surfaces we see that $X$ itself is the sphere or the plane, and so $\tilde\gamma = \partial D$ for some embedded disc $D \subset X$. The idea is now to prove that the restriction $f \mid D : D \to S$ is injective, and it will then follow that $f(D)$ is an embedded disc with $\partial(f(D)) = \gamma$.

Consider the deck transformation action of $\pi_1 S$ on $X$. To prove that $f \mid D$ is injective, it is equivalent to prove that for each deck transformation $T$, if $T$ is not the identity then $D \cap (T\cdot D) = \emptyset$.

Suppose that $D \cap (T\cdot D) \ne \emptyset$. There are two cases.

In the first case, suppose that $\partial D \cap (T \cdot \partial D) = \emptyset$. The Schönflies Theorem tells us that $D$ is one of the two components of $X - \partial D = X - \tilde\gamma$, and similarly $T \cdot D$ is one of the two components of $X - \partial (T \cdot D) = X - (T \cdot \tilde\gamma)$. It follows that either $D \subset T \cdot D$ or $T \cdot D \subset D$. In either case, the Brouwer Fixed Point Theorem implies that $T$ has a fixed point. Since $T$ is a deck transformation, it follows that $T$ is the identity.

In the second case, suppose that $\partial D \cap (T \cdot \partial D) \ne \emptyset$, and so for some $x,y \in \partial D = \tilde\gamma$ we have $T \cdot x = y$. If $x=y$ then $T$ is the identity, as in the previous case. If $x \ne y$ then we have $f(x)=f(y)$ and so $f \mid \tilde\gamma$ is not injective, contradicting that $\tilde\gamma$ is a homeomorphic lift of $\gamma$.

Comment: In the first case of $D\cap (T\cdot D)\neq \emptyset$, I am not sure it follows that either $D\subset T\cdot D$ or $T\cdot D\subset D$. 

If $X = \mathbb{R}^2$ I do, but if $X = S^2$, then I can see a sphere with two parallels for $\tilde{\gamma}, T\cdot\tilde{\gamma}$ (like Artic circle and Antarctic circle), while $D$ and $T\cdot D$ are the regions south and north of each circle, respectively. Then neither of the disks contains the other.

Comment: Good point. That case only arises when $S=P^2$, and when it does happen you can replace $D$ with the disc on the other side of $\tilde\gamma$.

Comment: I upvoted your answer. Another point I wanted to raise is that you mentioned that from the classification of surfaces we see that $X$ itself is the sphere or the plane. I know this is true for compact surfaces, but since the classification of noncompact surfaces is much more complicated, I'm not sure the only simply-connected surfaces (and thus the only universal covers) are the sphere or the plane. Is there a good reference for that?

(If they were, then we know that for the noncompact surfaces the plane is their universal cover since the cover of a noncompact surface can't be compact).

Comment: For any closed surface $S$ one can construct, in a reasonably straightforward manner using geometry, a universal covering map $X \mapsto S$ where $X$ is either the sphere or the plane. It is also true that every simply connected surface is homeomorphic to the sphere or plane.

Comment: Sorry, I think my last comment was not so clear. 
What if the surface is not closed, i.e., a non-compact, open surface? 
Is there a reference for the fact that the only non-compact simply-connected surface is $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: That's a good question, I don't know a good reference off hand. For a sketch of a proof, assuming paracompactness and using big tools analysis of analysis: choose a smooth structure on the surface; then choose a Riemannian metric; then take the induced conformal structure; and then apply the uniformization theorem. One can also apply the classification of noncompact surfaces, which as you say is complicated. I suspect there is an easier proof than either of these, but I don't know one offhand.

Comment: Perhaps one can extract an easier proof from the proof of the classification of noncompact surfaces, throwing away lots of parts of that proof that are not relevant to the question at hand.